InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error how to solve it in tensor flow
I'm trying to train an encoder-decoder model using InceptionV3 as the encoder and an LSTM-based decoder. I'm facing an error related to GPU compatibility. Here is the part of my code that causes the issue:
# Use InceptionV3 as a Pre-Trained Model for Feature Extraction
`from tensorflow.keras.applications import InceptionV3
from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_v3 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, TimeDistributed, Dense, Input, GlobalAveragePooling2D, RepeatVector
import tensorflow as tf

print("Using InceptionV3 for feature extraction...")
base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
`
# Define encoder
`input_layer = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3), dtype='float32')
preprocessed = preprocess_input(input_layer)
features = base_model(preprocessed)
flat_features = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(features)
encoded_features = Dense(256, activation='relu')(flat_features)  # Example size
`
# Define LSTM decoder
`decoder_input = Input(shape=(256,), dtype='float32')
repeated_layer = RepeatVector(20)(decoder_input)  # Example size
lstm_1 = LSTM(512, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.3)(repeated_layer)
output_layer = TimeDistributed(Dense(1000, activation='softmax'))(lstm_1)
`
# Compile the Encoder-Decoder Model
`model_input = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3), dtype='float32')
encoded_features = Dense(256, activation='relu')(flat_features)
decoded_output = TimeDistributed(Dense(1000, activation='softmax'))(encoded_features)
encoder_decoder_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
`
# Train the Model
`encoder_decoder_model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), batch_size=16, epochs=5)

`# Save the Model
`encoder_decoder_model.save('Trained_Model_with_InceptionV3_and_GloVe.h5')

Issue: When I run the code, I get the following error:
InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error: No DNN in stream executor.

I have tried forcing the code to run on CPU, but I still encounter the issue.
Question: How can I resolve this error and properly train my model using InceptionV3 and LSTM? Is there any specific configuration I need to modify for GPU compatibility, or should I change how TensorFlow interacts with my hardware?
